# How to convert EPSG:28992 to EPSG:4326?

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, mathematics

I have a list of coordinates which I need to convert to longitude and latitude in the following way:

[image]

What are the math transformations and formulas used to achieve this?

Comment: probably long and complex, you would better off using an established library

Comment: You can have a glimpse on complexity of calculations here: https://www.iogp.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/373-07-02.pdf. [PROJ](https://proj.org/download.html) and it's derivatives (like [proj4.js](http://proj4js.org/)) can do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

All the Formulas are provided here:
https://www.iogp.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/373-07-02.pdf